# Chat não está a funcionar

Tags: bug, status-pronto, chat

Todos os chat's do site estão fora do ar. É só comigo ou com toda a gente?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: voltou pra nossa alegria :D

Comment: [meta-tag:status-pronto]?

Comment: @Jefferson não sei.